If $f^{-1}(I)$ is a Borel set for every interval $I$, why is $f^{-1}(B)$ a Borel set for every Borel set $B$?
My book defines a Borel subset of an interval $X$ of $\mathbb R$ to be any set which is in every $\sigma$-field containing all finite unions of intervals in $X$. Then they define a function $f:X\to [0, \infty]$ to be measurable if, for every Borel set $B\subseteq [0, \infty]$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel subset of $X$.
Then they say that since $f^{-1}$ "preserves set theoretic operations", if $f^{-1}(I)$ is a Borel subset of $X$ for all intervals $I\subseteq [0, \infty]$, then $f$ is measurable. How does this follow? The definition of a Borel set doesn't give me any way to express it in terms of set theoretic operations applied to intervals.

Indeed, this is a bad explanation, they should have added more details. In short, the collection ${A\subseteq [0,\infty]: f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{B}(X)}$ is a sigma algebra on $[0,\infty]$, as it is very easy to check. So if it contains a generating set of the Borel sigma algebra then it by definition must contain the whole Borel sigma algebra.

Thanks! (If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it btw)

You're welcome. Ok, I added an answer.

This is indeed a bad explanation, they should have added more details. In short, the collection $\{A\subseteq [0,\infty]: f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{B}(X)\}$ is a sigma algebra on $[0,\infty]$, this is easy to check. So if it contains a generating set of the Borel sigma algebra then it by definition must contain the whole sigma algebra.
